# Which certificate does the browser see when nginx acts as a reverse proxy to an https internal server (also nginx)

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I currently have an internal http/2 (https) web site which uses self signed certificates.  The site is purely internal and has no need of (in fact it is for now prohibited) external access.  Most users have the self signed certificate authority's certificate installed, but some don't and its a pain.

I am planning for a future in which this application is dockerised and will sit on a synology NAS. Synology allow the use of a reverse proxy which can automatically obtain Lets Encrypt certificates for the proxy if the firewall port forwards port 80 to it.   Lets assume you can get a certificate for `myapp.example.com`. I'm not 100% sure where the NAS stores these certificates. I am hoping it doesn't matter. Port 443 remains closed.

Now if port 443 remains closed on your external firewall but you tell your local dns server that the ip address of `myapp.example.com` is the ip address of the Synology NAS.  Internal uses who navigate to `https://myapp.example.com` will get served up the proxied web site, where as external uses will get nothing (connection refused).

The question I have is; will the browser get served up the Lets encrypt certificate from the first reverse proxy or the self signed one from the second Nginx server.  As I said I am hoping the former as that solves the self signed certificate problem, but also prevents the need for the docker container to have a volume to link the certificate to, which is subject to what ever Synology decide to do in their next release.

UPDATE

After reading the answer to a different question elsewhere this question becomes irrelevant.  The reverse proxy sits on the same machine as the docker container is running.  Therefore there is negligible saving not to proxy to an http server, which doesn't need certificates.  So the proxy handles the lets encrypt certificate and no certificate is used in the internal dockerised nginx server as it only has port 80 open (although the docker -p specification alters that to a different one unique to that containers host)

Comment: I think you should ask it in other forums, like https://serverfault.com/ or https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/